# Subprocess: get stdout from sigle line

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

Being a Python noob I need to run a third party application (which writes its stdout into single line, they probably use something like `skip_eol=True`), from within my python script and display the app's stdout live.

This

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line.rstrip()
```

only allows me to get the stdout once the child process completed.
I don't clearly understand how do I catch the entire stdout?

Comment: Are you sure the output of your `cmd` is a binary file?

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import subprocess
import shlex

process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('./bash_1_line_per_second.sh'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while process.poll() is None:
    print 'reading' # Just to understand better what is happening
    print process.stdout.read(1)
```

This reads one character at time... is the output of cmd binary? In that case this probably wont work...

If you provide the output of cmd I can be more precise! In particular, if you need help to rebuild the line from the single characters.

This is the bash script I used to test:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
while [[ "a" == "a" ]]; do
  echo -n "This is the line number $counter"
  let counter+=1
  sleep 1
  if [[ $counter -eq 5 ]]; then 
      exit 0
  fi
done
```

Comment: it still waits until the child process finishes

Comment: @hdf I edited the example to work as you required (I think)

Comment: I'm getting `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` so far trying to run the Python script you've provided. Looking for what might be causing it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running your command or my bash script as subprocess?

Comment: running your script

Comment: Then it is quite probably you did not make the script "executable". Use `chmod +x <name_of_the_script>`

Comment: yeah, that was the case :) Now, however, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'` for `process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: could you post your `cmd`? If without `shlex.split` it works then do not use it... (it is only to create the list to use as command). Otherwise post all the error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128278/discussion-between-riccardo-petraglia-and-hdf).